# Beginner "Learn Python 3 the hard way" ex 5, and 6. Chromebook w/ Linux beta vs repl.it

Tags: python

Here's the script I'm trying to run, based off of Zed Shaw's Learn Python3 the hard way book.

```
      name = 'Zed A.Shaw'
      age = 35 # not a lie
      height = 74 # inches
      weight = 180 # lbs
      eyes = 'Blue'
      teeth = 'White'
      hair = 'Brown'
      inches_to_centimeters = 2.54
      lbs_to_kg = 0.45
      centimeters = "centimeters"
      kilograms = "kilograms"
      height = round(height * inches_to_centimeters)
      weight = round(weight * lbs_to_kg)

      print(f"Let's talk about {name}.")
      print(f"He's {age} years old.")
      print(f"He's {height} {centimeters} tall.")
      print(f"He's {weight} {kilograms} heavy.")
      print(f"Actually, that's not too heavy.")
      print(f"He's got {eyes} eyes and {hair} hair.")
      print(f"His teeth are usually {teeth} depending on the coffee.")


      total = age + height + weight
      print(f"If I add {age}, {height}, and {weight} I get {total}.")
```

I've tried it in a million different ways, but I'm pretty sure this is without flaws. Anywho, I can't get the bugger to run.
I keep getting this:

```
       File "ex5.py", line 15
           print(f"Let's talk about {name}.")
                                          ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I've tried removing the quotes, putting them elsewhere, single quotes, removing the format function altogether. Nothing. Same error.

Weird part is, I put this code into
https://repl.it/languages/python3

and it works. Just like it's supposed to.
I updated my VM right before posting this question and tried it out, to no avail.

Any thoughts?
I'm new to coding and computers in general. I'm running Linux Beta on chromebook, and I'm using Caret as my text editor
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are be running your code in Python version less than 3.6 which does not support f-strings, i.e. format strings with the `f` prefix.

For example in Python 2.7:

```
Python 2.7.16 (default, Jul 13 2019, 16:01:51)
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux2
>>> name = 'bobo'
>>> print(f"Let's talk about {name}.")
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print(f"Let's talk about {name}.")
                                    ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using formatted string literals (https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-pep498) with python version < 3.6.

When running your code on https://repl.it/languages/python3, which runs on newest pyhton version, there is no error.

If you try running in older version of python, like https://repl.it/languages/python, same error occurs.

So you either need to update your python version to 3.6, or not use formatted string literals.